# How would the world's superpowers overcome the fog of war without any satellite left in orbit?

Tags: science-based, warfare, kessler-syndrome, telecommunications

A bit of context : I want to come up with a cascade of events involving a breakdown, even temporary, of international powers' ability to keep tabs on each other's armies.

The situation is, due to a sudden Kessler Effect, all satellites are rendered useless. Previous to this, satellites were the most potent means for militaries to keep themselves informed about others militaries' sites and maneuvers. Which have all be reduced to shreds along with everything in orbit.

In such an event, and based on today's technology, what could the world's powers (especially the biggest ones) do to overcome the fog of war?

Comment: There isn't a thickness metric to fog of war. Analyzing all the consequences of not having satellites is too broad an ask to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Given that the Kessler Effect is a known risk now, if that risk elevated then the military forces would have already taken steps to either mitigate the risk (clear the orbits) or accept it and put alternative measures in place.  Most military forces already teach their forces not to rely on GPS (although the standard of training is vital here).  However, the question is unanswerable without knowing what military operations and forces look like in the time period, especially autonomous drone capabilities and inertial navigation technologies.

Comment: Hello Kubler! Thanks for joining us on [worldbuilding.se]. We need you to modify your Q a bit to become on-topic for our site, and I hope you're willing to do this because I think there's a good worldbuilding question here. We require focused, specific questions. so (a) Clearly state that the Kessler Effect stuff is only BACKGROUND. It's only the rationalization you're using to justify the CONDITION of your question: all the satellites become inoperative in a short period of time. (b) Then ask a simple, specific, focused Q. I'd recommend, "Given today's technology and the (\*continued\*)

Comment: ...condition I've specified, what methods would be used by the world's super powers to overcome the fog of war?" I believe (but it would be up to the community to agree) that such a list question (which we don't like but will permit given restrictions, see [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) vs [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609))) would be on-topic and permitted. And I think you'd get a lot of what you're looking for. Would you be willing to [edit] your question to make it that focused?

Comment: Hey JBH! No problem, I see what the issue is, I will take time a bit later today to try and narrow my question down. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: there are a bunch of spy-planes. they already provide amazingly detailed battlefield information. welcome the return of the Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird. the biggest benefit of satellites is gps location data.

Comment: @Kubler I can't vote to reopen yet. You're allowed to ask one and only one question. Let's focus on what the super powers can do, because how much the fog of war can thicken is too story-based for this Stack (it will be as thick as you, the worldbuilder, want it to be, because you can always choose to enable or disable conditions of your story to change the thickness. Even a judgment of "worst" requires choices about what technologies are available - which is your choice, not ours or the Real World's).

Comment: And please note to use that "@" symbol. If you don't, I'm not notified of your response. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @JBH, I've dropped one of the question, I hope it's ok this time. Sorry for the hassle, I'm learning!

Comment: Thank you! I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Drones, Drones, Everywhere

@Postlim Fort in the comments suggested the SR-71 Blackbird, but the Blackbird was both wildly inefficient (it actually leaked fuel outright at lower altitudes than its designed cruising height) and overengineered in order to make intercepting it impossible.  Modern tech has a simpler solution - saturation.

Combine [Project Loon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loon_LLC) for connectivity with a mix of [solar-powered, high-altitude, infinite endurance UAVs](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337386694_Self-Powered_Solar_Aerial_Vehicles_Towards_Infinite_Endurance_UAVs), [conventional large-scale stealth drones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_RQ-170_Sentinel), and [small-scale close-in recon drones](https://www.aeroexpo.online/aeronautic-manufacturer/reconnaissance-uav-563.html), and fog of war will be annihilated.

We could do most of this now, but it's broadly cheaper to deploy a couple of satellites than to deploy a drone network.  If the militaries of the world had their hands forced, I imagine it would be rapidly expedited.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! By any chance, do you have any timescale in mind when you say "rapidly"? The militaries would obviously be in quite a hurry, but are we talking days or weeks?

Comment: @Kubler - depends on whether you want global coverage or just a specific region (for active combat or something).  For a specific region, it could probably be achieved immediately, at the price of exhausting stores of extant drones.  If you wanted to replace the use of satellites militarily globally, we'd be talking years, as the manufacture of the necessary drone types would be scaled up.

Comment: @Kubler - because of the better images achievable from in-atmosphere flybys, militaries are already exploring this solution:
* India's [Infinity Drone](https://www.thedefensepost.com/2021/02/05/india-solar-drone-infinity/)
* Airbus' [Zephyr](https://www.airbus.com/en/products-services/defence/uas/uas-solutions/zephyr)

Answer (score 1):

This is a frame challenge (which I myself hate receiving, so I know how you feel lol)

I'm not meaning to be fault-finding about your scenario, but I think the vast majority of GPS and other medium- to high-orbit satellites would remain totally unaffected by the shenanigans in low-orbit, where the Kessler syndrome mostly occurs (300-2,000 km altitude) ([we have many times more LEO satellites than any other](https://aerospace.csis.org/aerospace101/earth-orbit-101/#:%7E:text=The%20majority%20of%20satellites%20orbiting,relative%20closeness%20to%20the%20Earth.)). It takes additional orbital energy to reach higher orbits, energy measured in whatever rocket fuel is measured in that inanimate debris just doesn't have.
Inter-debris collisions can be thought of as little orbital "burns". Collisions that may have otherwise raised the apogee of debris to reach a higher orbit has also lowered its perigee, which at LEO means the perigee is now intersecting the atmosphere, and the object burns up.
[image: perigee-apogee movement]

(Note: image not to scale. To imagine orbits at LEO, shrink the circle until it's a hair's breadth from Earth's surface and you'll see why slight changes in the orbital shape means intersection with the atmosphere.)

In addition to that, the raised-apogee object had to steal orbital energy from the other object it previously collided with, which means both objects are closer to intersecting the atmosphere. Without a sequence of lucky, consecutive "burns", debris is unlikely to raise itself to higher orbits and interfere with other satellites (such as the spy satellites we have sitting stationary above other nations, ~40,000 km up.).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input! I'm a bit surprised by your statement that spy satellites sit 40,000 km up, all my Internet research seemed to confirm my intuition that they would be placed in low orbit in order to provide optimal quality pictures. Could you be talking about another specific type of spy satellites?

Comment: As for the likelyhood of medium and high orbits to be affected by a Kessler effect, it would be another question entirely in my case as I have left aside numerous factors specific to my lore – the events will take place in the early 2100's, the amount and types of satellites places on either orbits will have drastically evolved, I haven't decided the exact cause of the KE yet, etc. It's probably preferable for now to just assume that a generalized KE has occured in order to stay on topic!

Comment: @Kubler I'm sure some proportion of spy satellites sit at lower orbits for that resolution boost, but to monitor a nation 24/7, for things like early launch detection and troop mobilization, many spy satellites sit at geostationary altitude. Crunching a little rough math, a 2.4 m mirror of an optical telescope (Hubble's mirror size; IIRC, Hubble was based off US spy satellites) at 36,000 km, I get a resolution on the ground of ~5 m^2, enough to make out buildings, planes, launches, troops, etc. I'm sure interferometry methods boost that figure some, too.

Comment: @Kubler If I had to suggest an alternative, I'd say an EM attack would be more likely to take out those spy satellites. A large, powerful, directional dish of some sort, either harnessing some serious power and frying the electrics out of the things in orbit, or some kind of targeted software attack. Many satellites use gyroscopics to stay oriented and point in different directions. If the control systems go haywire and the gyroscopes become saturated, it becomes impossible to orient the telescope and the whole thing becomes a pile of junk (or a new Hubble that points nowhere in particular)

Comment: Satellites also don't have too many redundancies. An EM attack may break the right things, like power regulation junctions, computer memory, controllers, the comms antenna, etc. Losses like those mean loss of the whole system.

Comment: That's very useful information, thanks a lot. Are these satellites equipped with course-correcting hardware other than gyroscopes? In your opinion, how credible is a scenario where such hardware (or the gyroscopes themselves if they're potent enough), because of a cyber or EM attack, would malfunction to the extent of severely altering the orbit of the satellite?

Comment: @Kubler this'll very much be my opinion, because I don't know much about spy sats. On modern chemical rockets, "every ounce counts", and reaction mass to significantly alter the sat's orbit just isn't important. The rocket stage delivering the sat to GEO does all the heavy lifting. It's probable the sat has a small amount of delta-v for course corrections, *maybe* 10-50 m/s, but such maneuvers wouldn't be common at GEO. I can't think of a realistic instance where it would be needed.

Comment: @Kubler if the cold gas thrusters malfunction and burn themselves completely empty, the orbit might get a little wobbly, doing a figure-eight in the sky overhead, but no significant change in orbital shape. If the gyros fail, the satellite either can't orient itself anymore and is stuck looking at whatever it's looking at, or put itself into a spin and is staring into the void, its gaze possibly sweeping Earth on occasion. A software attack could purposefully orient the sat to space and saturate the gyros. An EM attack would rely on destroying fragile systems, rendering the whole thing junk.

Comment: @Kubler Er, I should mention, I've been using the wrong terminology. *Reaction wheels* are used to orient the spacecraft while *gyros* are used to detect/sense orientation. It's possible to *de-saturate* gyros with a second attitude control system (thrusters), but saturated gyros alone might not be good enough to decommission a satellite. EM/software attack, damaging critical hardware like the computer, is likely the best bet.

Comment: Yep, don't worry you got the point across, and it did provide me with a practical solution to make the blackout happen – I was simply reaching to see if I could kill two birds with one stone, but the second bird is beside the point of the question anyways. Thanks a lot for your help!